# Inconsistent text field.TouchDown firing when using a ScrollView

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I'm using a UIScrollView for the first time, and I'm going crazy. I have several text boxes and labels on the scrollview. My text box event handled for TouchedDown,  HandleTbLocationTouchDown (tb = Textbox), isn't firing half the time. My guess would be that the scrollview is swallowing the event because I have the exact same functionality on another View and it works perfectly fine.

Also, I set the size of the ScrollView in IB but that doesn't let it be scrollable. Setting it programmatically in my ViewDidLoad works though.

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();


        // Set the scrollableview
        scrollView.Frame = new RectangleF(0,20, 320, 460);
        // Set the initial scrollable view area size
        scrollView.ContentSize = new SizeF(320, 550);

        // For some reason this isn't always firing to do the offset,
        // but the keyboard ALWAYS comes up.

        tbLocation.TouchDown += HandleTbLocationTouchDown;
    }

    void HandleTbLocationTouchDown (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            scrollView.SetContentOffset(new PointF(0, 130), true);
    }
```

Help?

Comment: could you use the `EditingDidstart` for the textfield instead?

Comment: That event fires every time, so I've switched to that. I'm sure the issue is that the ScrollView becomes the first responder or that there's some event swallowing going on.